# Problems to use a simulated index on an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to choose randomly the first `random_col` columns of the matrix `ms`. But I keep getting an error. I try this:

```
import random
random.seed(42)

# ms is a matrix of nxm, with some random values
n = 5
m = 8
ms = np.zeros((n,m),int)
for i in range(0,n):
  ms[i,:] = random.choices(range(10), k=m)

# Let us take a random column
random_col = random.choices(range(m), k=1)

# Since we fix the seed, the value of random_col is 5
print(random_col) 

# Why I can use this?
ms[:,0:5]
ms[:,random_col]

# But not this?
ms[:,0:random_col]
```

But I get this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-159-31ca1de6d10b> in <module>
     20 
     21 # But not this?
---> 22 ms[:,0:random_col]
     23 
     24 

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: `random.choices()` returns a list, `ms[:,0:random_col]` needs an integer.  You can use `ms[:, 0:random_col[0]]` or `random_col = random.choices(range(m), k=1)[0]`.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterK, your comments solve my problem!!!, Thanks!!!